# Why didn't all three of my electrical fuses ignite?

Tags: electric-circuits, rocket-science, electrical-engineering

I built a rocket that used 3 x solid fuel motors. To ignite them I used 3 electrical fuses, which are basically a thin filament of wire which heats up when given enough voltage.

Only 2 of the 3 fuses ignited. WHY IS THAT?

The only thing that was different with the 3rd fuse was that I ran longer wires from the main electrics (the breakaway junction) running off the 14.4V battery.

Does this have something to do with the path of least resistance?

[image: Circuit diagram]

Comment: it is hard to answer precisely in this question, except some plausible remarks

Comment: it might relate to time taken to ignite the fuses and any length difference betwen the fuses, it might be a broken fuse, it might be any spike currents when fuses were ignited, etc..

Comment: I can confirm that the fuse wasn't broken. After the two motors ignited (the ones running the shorter wires) I broke those wires off the rig and successfully ignited the fuse that failed to ignite.

Comment: This is a clip of the rockets two stages of ignition.

http://instagram.com/p/u276AErEzS/?modal=true

Part 1: the Two motors in the head of the rocket ignite. The motor in the rear of the rocket fails to ignite. Even though I hold the battery connection on for a good 8 seconds.

Part 2: I break away the burnt fuses and eliminate them from the circuit, then I try to re-fire. The Launch is a success.

Comment: VIDEO LINK: http://instagram.com/p/u276AErEzS/?modal=true (same as above)

Comment: Possibly one of the other wire pairs ended up shorting after the rocket ignited - preventing sufficient current from reaching the third fuse.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about speculation of possible causes, not a physical concept.

Comment: Circuit was wired in parallel. Its suggested with this type of fuse. I have successfully ignited 6 motors on the very same battery and wires in the past.

Comment: I'm under the assumption that the theory of 'PATH OF THE LEAST RESISTANCE' is at play here?

The fuse that didn't ignite used a wire approx 1.5 m (5ft) longer than the wires that were rigged to the other two successful fuses.

Comment: This VIDEO edit shows the failed ignition attempt, with only two of the three motors igniting. Then I show the circuit used.

http://youtu.be/E4gQb-rZYTQ

Comment: Watch the clip closely. At 10 approx seconds all the way through to approx 20 seconds you can see the two successful fuses still holds a full circuit and glow white hot (lower left of frame)... The main motor in the body doesn't ignite. After breaking away the two spent fuses, I try again and the 3rd motor (main body motor) ignites.

This is my second attempt at this spin stabilised rocket experiment, hence why I believe its something to do with 'The path of least resistance'. I'm just not 100% because I don't know a whole lot about the science of electricity.

Comment: In this different experiment I successfully ignited 6 x motors using the very same 14.4V battery and the same electrical speaker cable. Wired again in parallel, the only difference is that each fuse was connected to the circuit using an equal length of wire. ignitions was spontaneous and all 6 motors pushed that rocket very high and very fast. Exactly what I hoped for, because if one motor was ignited out of sync the entire rocket could have been thrown off course. 

VIDEO: http://instagram.com/p/h-2noirEyl/?modal=true

Comment: Maybe I'm posting in the wrong type of forum. Can anyone direct me to a forum that would offer a better solution for my question?